# Can you change the color of the UINavigationBar and status bar separately?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view that I'm trying to 'dim'. I'm creating a UIView with a black background color and alpha of 0.4. I lay this view over my view, and I also change the color of my of navigationbar by change the RGB values (the correct way to get this is to take the RGB value and multiply it by 1.0-0.4 to get 0.6. Anyway, that's beside point).

I want to 'dim' my main view, and 'dim' the UINavigationBar... but I don't want the status bar to be 'dimmed'.

However, I can't figure out how to do this. When I change `[self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar setBarTintColor:`

Is there a way to set the colors individually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're on the right track, You can set the color of the bar by using these methods, the barTintColor

//Navigation Bar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar   setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:53.0/255.0 green:53.0/255.0 blue:53.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: how do you change the status bar up top to a different color than the navigationbar?

Comment: After iOS 7, the status bar takes the color of the navigation controller you implement, so choose the transparent one so that it takes the color of the UINavigationBar, or I have tried to even overlay a view of that size and put it under auto-layout or change the size on notification of orientation change

Comment: check this website out http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/